# Which kind of distance is this one? I want to compare if two images (matrices) are the same

Tags: matrices, algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a loss function for my neuronal network and I don't know if it is a distance already implemented.

I want to compare two black and white images to know how different the two images are:

1. One image will be the original image, the one I want to get from the neuronal network.
2. The other image will be the predicted image from the neuronal network.

To do it, I have considered that two images are the same if both images has the same white pixel at the same location (x,y).

Both images will have black pixels, with value 0.0, and white pixels, with value 1.0.

So, using this information, I think if I sum both images (computationally, images are matrices) and count how many 2.0 values are in this sum, and compare it with the number of pixels with value 1.0 in the original image, I will know if both images are the same or not.

Is this a known distance?

I used Euclidean distance, but I'm not sure if I can use it know if both images are the same.

Comment: A distance needs to satisfy a few properties. It needs to be greater than zero, the distance between the same image is 0, and it needs to be convex. Your function doesn't seem to be convex

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Thanks. I want to compare if two images (matrices) are the same. In other words, if both images has 1.0 values and 0.0 values at the same locations. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Simply count the pixels that differ. This is called the Hamming distance.

Comment: Someone cares to explain his deletion vote ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know a lot of mathematics, and maybe I'm going to say something wrong. Someone has talked me that I need a differentiable function to use it on my neuronal network, that allows me to compute gradients. He said that Hamming distance is not. Is there something similar to that I want to do that it is differentiable? Thanks again.

Comment: @VansFannel: this is nonsense. In all cases, digital image comparison metrics are applied to discrete pixel values. non-differentiability does not cause a problem. This does not tell me why there are votes for deletion.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about your deletion vote. I'm asking you about this: Is there something similar to Hamming Distance that it is differentiable? Thanks.