# Is there any distance (or function) differentiable to denote how similar are two images (or two matrices)?

Tags: derivatives, algorithms

I'm trying to implement a loss function for my neuronal network and I don't know if it is a distance already implemented.

I want to compare two black and white images to know how different the two images are:

1. One image will be the original image, the one I want to get from the neuronal network.
2. The other image will be the predicted image from the neuronal network.

To do it, I have considered that two images are the same if both images has the same white pixel at the same location (x,y).

Both images will have black pixels, with value 0.0, and white pixels, with value 1.0.

So, using this information, my suggestion is:

> If I sum both images (computationally, images are matrices) and count
>   how many 2.0 values are in this sum, and compare it with the number of
>   pixels with value 1.0 in the original image, I will know if both
>   images are the same or not.

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713624/which-kind-of-distance-is-this-one-i-want-to-compare-if-two-images-matrices-a), someone told me that it is the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

But I can use it because Hamming Distance is not differentiable (by the way, I have not a lot of idea about mathematics and the last sentence could be wrong).

Is there any other distance (or function) that compares two images (or two matrices) to check if they are equal?

I want to know how similar they are.

Comment: I don't know about the function you are asking for, but I think you should also consider the case where one image is the negative of the other. That means the second has white where the first one has black, light gray where the first has dark gray and so on. Two images like these are quite similar to the human eye so you should be able to determine this as well

Comment: I'm going to count how many 1.0 are on the sum images and check that is equal to the count of 1.0 in the original image. That's you are suggesting is not going to affect my algorithm. Thanks.